# How to automatically run ftp without -s flag?

Tags: windows, cmd, ftp

I'm working with a piece of hardware that I need to retrieve files from automatically that has a very rudimentary version of the ftp program on it. What this boils down to is that I cannot run ftp using the -s flag and a file with ftp commands on it. However, if I use the exact same commands in the same order from cmd (thus losing the automation I need), I am able to retrieve the files I need. I'm looking for any solution that might exist as I've already tried quite a few options.

What I've already tried:

- ftp -s:filename.txt; server response - command not implemented
- Matlab's built in ftp library; same issue as ftp -s
- Python ftp library; same issue
- running ftp from telnet; unable to even connect
- running ftp from a cmd process in c#; unable to write input to ftp program after starting it up (there might be potential here that I'm missing because I've never used c# before now)

Any advice is appreciated. I'm working in Windows 7, if that's relevant.

** contents of filename.txt **

```
open <192.168.100.220>


get Disk00
quit
```

** output from running -s command **

```
ftp -s:filename.txt
open 192.168.100.220
Connected to 192.168.100.220
220 Service Ready
User <192.168.100.220:>none>>:
331 User OK, Need Password

230 User Logged In
ftp> get Disk00
202 [2,16] Command Not Implemented
150 Opening Data Connection
```

At this point the process just hangs and I have to ctrl+c out of it. The command issued that is apparently "not implemented" in the ftp software that's onboard what I'm working with is the raw PORT command.

[Image of cmd when running line by line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV6ER.png)

Disk00 is in the default directory. I'm pretty sure that the issue I'm encountering is an innate issue with how the hacky version of ftp I have on this piece of hardware interprets, or in this case, misinterprets the commands sent from the batch file I'm using. The output from the failed PORT command when running from a batch file indicates that somehow it's misindexing the command. From Wireshark:

```
Request: PORT 192,168,100,100,230,70
Response: 202 [2,16] Command Not Implemented
```

This is why my original question is more of how could I implement a workaround for this to avoid whatever bizarre behavior this version of ftp code is doing.

** UPDATE **

When testing random combinations of commands in the file I'm passing to ftp with the -s flag, I fixed my problem by calling PORT before using the get command... One of the PORT commands still fails so I'm not sure exactly why it works but I'm not going to question it....

Comment: Can you copy and paste into the question the contents of `filename.txt`? Can you copy and paste into the question the output reporting "command not implemented?"

Comment: Please edit the question to copy and paste the output of the command `TYPE filename.txt` that you are using. Likewise, copy and paste any messages that appear into the question. Use the `{}` icon in the editor to make filename.txt more readable.

Comment: This is weird. Are you sure that the file `Disk00` is in the default directory? Instead of `get`, try using `ls` to see if it will give a directory listing.

Comment: Show us a screenshot of a successful download, when typing the commands manually.